# Spark job can't find local dependency on remote server

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've got a *very* basic spark job, in Java. If I build the jar and send it to the remote server it runs via spark-submit without error.

If, in Eclipse, I run the main class it connects to the remote ResourceManager and then errors:

```
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-yarn_2.10/1.5.0/spark-yarn_2.10-1.5.0.jar does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Of course the file doesn't exist on the remote Linux box, but does exist on the local OSX box. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: you'll need to assembly an uber-jar to send it to a remote server

Comment: A non-uber jar works fine remotely. I want to run it locally to avoid sending the jar.